# KDB create null table with schema of preexisting table

Tags: schema, kdb

Imagine I have some populated table T_old with a given schema (lets say mix of ints, floats, symbols, etc.)  I now want to create a new empty/null table T_new that has the same exact schema as T_old.  How do I do this?  In the end, I would like both of these operations to be valid: T_old uj T_new, and T_new uj T_old.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

You can do `T_new:0#T_old`. That way you keep the exact schema and column type of the old schema.

Then your operations `T_old uj T_new` and `T_new uj T_old` should yield the same result.

Comment: The give him a nice green tick :)

Answer (score 0):

There are some hacks through which you can copy only plain schema of a table. By plain Schema I mean you can't get exact schema.

So it is kind of hack where you take 0 rows from one table and copy it to new table(variable). In real, we are no copying schema.

**Way1: Take Operator:** `newtbl:0# oldtbl`

**Way2: Select Command:** `newtbl:select from oldtbl where i=-1`

Both are nothing but taking 0 rows from old tbl.

**Issue:** But this will not copy all the attributes in schema. So for example if you have sorted attribute on some column in old table, that will not get copied to new table schema.

Comment: good point re attributes, but it makes sense to that they would be dropped IMO, since you can't have attributes without data, and 0# effectively does that. You will still have the added value of type checks for `upsert` etc and you can apply attributes after

Comment: You are right. I mentioned sorted attribute  just for an example to explain my point. I haven't tested other attributes, so don't know whether copying schema  through these ways will work on them.

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, I didn't really check other attributes, assumed that the same will happen with those, but guess that things with attributes aren't exactly uniform (especially when you consider that things like `asc` assign a vector the `\`s#` attribute, but `distinct` does not automatically assign a vector a `\`u#` attribute)